# gcloud app deploy failed with error - gcloud crashed FileNotFoundError - python3 app

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a sample python app which I got from another tutorial. However, the deployment fails as below:

> gcloud app deploy Beginning deployment of service [default]... ERROR:
>   gcloud crashed (FileNotFoundError): [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory:
>   '/Users/nileshdeshmukh/Desktop/Training/Python/FlaskIntroduction-master/env/.Python'

My app.yaml file is as below:

```
runtime: python3
env: standard

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

I have all dependencies copied in env/bin but the build process is looking for env only..

I think the problem would be solved if the deployment process looks at env/bin, but don't know how to force it to look at given path

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, some `gcloud` commands use `.gitignore` file to prevent sending useless file to Cloud for building your app.

You can override this behavior by [creating a .gcloudignore file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore). Same syntax as git ignore but take into account only by `gcloud` commands and not by git. By the way you can differentiate the file to send to the cloud and file to send to git

Comment: I can't force ignore python executable.. wont the app fail

Answer (score 0):

The `runtime_config` setting is for App Engine [flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml) only and isn't needed for App Engine [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref). You can safely remove it.

As per the error, you should ensure that all your dependencies are self-contained and shipped with your app or listed in your `requirements.txt` file.